# Is there any way to make windows service application using JavaFx

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Is there any way to make windows service application using JavaFx.
I've tried few wrapper like jar2exe and got no success.
I want to create .exe file which on execution will run as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Try Launch4j, it seems to be working for simple projects:

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/